# Search Api custom field type

Tags: search

I have a field that concatenates multiple taxonomomy terms  into a single text field. I have altered the existing module concat_field.

This all works fine but I cannot get search API to recognize the field (it worked with an older version of search api)

I have added this to the module:

```
function concat_field_property_info_callback(&$info, $entity_type, $field, $instance, $field_type) {
  $property = &$info[$entity_type]['bundles'][$instance['bundle']]['properties'][$field['field_name']];

  $property['type'] ='text'; //tried concat_field as well which is the type in concat_field_field_info
  $property['getter callback'] = 'entity_metadata_field_verbatim_get';
  $property['setter callback'] = 'entity_metadata_field_verbatim_set';
  $property['label'] = 'Concat field';
  $property['description'] = 'concatenated field';   
  unset($property['query callback']);
}
```

Any clue what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I should have looked better at contrib modules, If anyone needs to achieve something similar, look into the computed field module. I just made a small custom module that creates a computed concatenated field. I used taxonomy terms, but you can concatenate any field.

My code:

```
 /**
computed_address is field name used by computed_field module, you can use any field that is created with computed_field module
*/

function computed_field_field_computed_address_compute(&$entity_field, $entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items) {

  $taxonomyterms = array('field_province', 'field_city', 'field_street'); //fields machinenames to concatenate
  $result = array();

  foreach ($taxonomyterms as $taxonomyterm) {

      $field_myterms = field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, $taxonomyterm);

            if (!empty($field_myterms)) {
                $term = taxonomy_term_load($field_myterms[0]['tid']);
            }

      $result[] = $term->name;
    }

    $entity_field[0]['value'] = implode(', ', $result);
}

function computed_field_computed_address_display($field, $entity_field_item, $entity_lang, $langcode, $entity) {
  return $entity_field_item['value'];
}
```

Maybe this will help anyone else...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to follow following approach:

```
 /**
 * Implements hook_entity_property_info_alter().
 */
function modulename_property_info_alter(&$info) {
  $info['node']['properties']['concat_field'] = array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'label' => t('Concatenated form of all the taxonomies that has been added to the node'),
    'sanitized' => TRUE,
    'getter callback' => 'modulename_search_api_property_concat_field_callback',
  );
}

/**
 * Getter callback for concatenate terms field.
 */
function modulename_search_api_property_concat_field_callback($item) {
  /** Do all your processing/functionality here. **/
  return <resultant concatenated value>;
}
```

Comment: I actually tried that, I also found in the search.api.php that its possible to register a new type.

As described here:

     *** Define new data types for indexed properties.

     function concat_field_search_api_data_type_info() {
         return array(
           'concat_field' => array(
           'name' => t('Concat Field'),
           'fallback' => 'string',
           ),
       );
     }

However still no luck, and it really seems that that is the way?

Comment: Please check this: http://dropbucket.org/node/614 . And you need to use hook_property_info_alter().

Comment: yea that one doesn't work anymore (I had this working with old search api)

Answer (score 0):

I actually tried that, I also found in the search.api.php that its possible to register a new type.

As described here:

```
 *** Define new data types for indexed properties.

 function concat_field_search_api_data_type_info() {
     return array(
       'concat_field' => array(
       'name' => t('Concat Field'),
       'fallback' => 'string',
       ),
   );
 }
```

However still no luck, and it really seems that that is the way?